# Two Dimensional Diagram with aggr function

Tags: qlikview

I'm having a very curious Problem in QlikView.

I have a number of readouts from a Database which show certain amounts of time in a different state.

In that table there are 49 variables that describe the state, there are 7 levels of i.e the SOC and seven states of the Temperature.

i.e the one of the fields could be named: SOC1_T1 or SOC2_T1 and so on...

So what i get is a table full of readouts in which every i have an specific id for the object, the state of the variables and an age. There are multiple entries per Object.

What i want to do is to plot a two dimensional diagram over all the states so i get SOC over Temperatur Histogram(Average of the maximum (or newest) value of every object).

I tried creating to Dynamic (or syntethic) Dimensions (ValueLoop(1,7) and ValueLoop(1,8). 
In the formulas i reffered to them with

```
=If(ValueLoop(1,7) = 1 and ValueLoop(1,8) = 1, 
 (avg(aggr(FirstSortedValue (SOC1_T1
  ,  -age), id)) * 100))
```

and created 49 Formulas with each state variable output.

Problem now is:
It only shows the first entry. I can replace the whole expression in the if condition with a specific number (100) and get a result. I also plotted the inner expression into a Listbox and checked wheter the result is not null.

As soon as I delete the aggr function and just take the AVG over everything (which is not what i want). Everything works fine. When i turn back to aggr, only the first one is shown.

Doesnt help by the way when i delete one of the dimensions, this doesnt work one dimensional either.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Greetings
Julian

Comment: Can you upload some sample data?